# Use Django with MongoDB and PostgreSQL at the same time

Tags: mongodb, postgresql, python-2.7, django-rest-framework, django-rest-auth

I have project written on Django Rest Framework. When i started project, i was using just PostgreSQL as main database. Now i need to use MongoDB as main database, but i faced with problem: framework that i used for authentication [rest-auth](https://github.com/Tivix/django-rest-auth), maybe should not work properly with MongoDB. So i have two questions:

1)Is it possible(i am asking about good practices) to use one database for users authentication, and another for business logic

2)If answer on first is "yes", can i referencing from MongoDB Model to PostgreSQL model? Something like that:

```
 class ToolInput(EmbeddedDocument):
 name = fields.StringField(required=True)
 user = fields.ReferenceField(User)
```

User - model that stored in PostgreSQL
settings.py stores connection to both databases :

```
DATABASES = {

'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
    'NAME':
    'USER':
    'PASSWORD':
    'HOST':
    'PORT': '5432',
    'CONN_MAX_AGE': 15000,
} 

mongoengine.connect(
db="tools",
host="localhost")
```

Sorry if this is duplication,but i didnt found nothing about this

Comment: @VonC, done, write what you want)